# Android Studio 2.2 blank AVD & VCPU Shutdown request

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, vcpu

I am using Android Studio 2.2 and when I try to do a trial run of hello world program, I am getting AVD with blank screen. Also In-between that the `VCPU shutdown request` coming in the log.I am not getting any android welcome screen after a long time (More Than 30 minutes). There is no issue with RAM performance, I already have 16gb. All the components are installed correctly from `SDK`. Can you help me to solve this issue? Please Find the Image below for **Blank AVD AS2.2**

[image]

Error Log:

```
C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\tools\emulator.exe -netdelay none -netspeed full -avd Nexus_5_API_24
Hax is enabled
Hax ram_size 0x40000000
HAX is working and emulator runs in fast virt mode.
emulator: Listening for console connections on port: 5554
emulator: Serial number of this emulator (for ADB): emulator-5554
emulator: emulator window was out of view and was recentered
VCPU shutdown request
EAX=00748cea EBX=3ffadb60 ECX=00000000 EDX=00000000
VCPU shutdown request
```

**UPDATE AFTER CHECKING WITH HAXM 6.0.5**

**Adding: Intel HAXM 6.0.5 not compatible with windows screenshot:**

[Intel HAXM 6.0.5 not compatible with windows screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7DhvZ.png)

Comment: Anybody Faced This issue before?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use 6.0.5 HAXM it solved for me. I have i7 and similar issues with 6.0.4

Comment: But Still my App is Not Getting Launched and Other Errors are fixed. the Stand alone SDK manger showing 'Intel HAXM 6.0.5 not compatible with windows'. Screenshot Added in Main Area.

Answer (score 0):

Dealing with the same issue. Something to do with haxm on 7th gen processors as the arm image works.

**UPDATE:** Confirmed to be a HAXM issue on Kaby Lake, nothing we can do until we get an HAXM update from Intel. Best workaround at this stage is to use the physical device or create a Linux partition. I haven't tested genymotion on a 7th gen processor...can anybody confirm if that works?

Comment: Yes. Hyper-V has been uninstalled and I switched it off before doing so.

Comment: Still my App is Not Getting Launched and Other Errors are fixed. the Stand alone SDK manger showing 'Intel HAXM 6.0.5 not compatible with windows'. Screenshot Added in Main Area.can you please help?

Comment: @AlbinShaju - Do you have an older processor?

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to share that I am experiencing the same problem as well with my new Windows 10 computer. How do you add the switch -accel off -verbose to the x86/x64 image? Running an ARM image is extremely slow.